# Embedding XLS files on a webpage

Tags: php, apache, excel, xls

I am having many XLS files and i want to embed that on a webpage.

How can i do this Dynamically ? I just want to provide the location to the XLS file and see the Content on the webpage

I am free to use both PHP / ASP

Comment: Better load Xls file in to gridview for ideas check this URL http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/43010-How-import-excel-data-into-dataset-using-File.aspx

Comment: Check this URL too http://forums.asp.net/p/1156251/1899198.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can embed the excel file with the HTML [`<object>`](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/the-iframe-element.html#the-object-element) element, like this:

```
<object data="document.xls" type="application/vnd.ms-excel">
You don't have an plugin for Excel documents.
<a href="document.xls">Download the file</a>.
</object>
```